# How to upload pdf file to s3 in javascript?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to uplaod a pdf file from UI(written in Javascript) to Amazon S3 but I am trying to upload the file to the S3, I am getting some unicode format text and when I copy that text to notepad, or say, any other text editor I can the human readable text

I am using pdfmake to get the content of the file and upload it using getBufffer method.

```
var content = generatePDF(base64Img);
pdfMake.createPdf(content).getBuffer(function (data) {//Code}
```

The code that i used to upload the file to S3.

```
 var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: file_name,
        Body: data.toString(),
        ContentType: 'application/pdf'
      }

      s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        // code 
        }else{
         //code
}
```

The file is getting uploaded successfully but I am getting the text like

```
!
 " #$%&!' ()*')+,
!
!
!
!
```

But I am pasting it to other text editor, I am getting

```
Date: 04/20/19
```

Comment: Just remove ToString() form data & then try.

Comment: When I remove the toString(), I get the below error:TypeError: a._set is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the above problem by passing the data from getBuffer to S3.
In S3, I passed to a buffer like

`var data = new Buffer(event.data, 'binary');`

uploaded the data to S3.

```
var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: file_name,
        Body: data,
        ContentType: 'application/pdf'
      }

      s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        // code 
        }else{
         //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To upload a file from client end directly to s3 bucket you can use [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3).

> FROM CLIENT END:

```
axios.post(url, data, {
        onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
          this.setState({
            loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total * 100),
          })
        },
      })
        .then(res => { // then print response status
          toast.success('Upload Success!')
        })
        .catch(err => { // then print response status
          toast.error('Upload Failed!')
        })
```

> SERVER SIDE:

```
    const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    acl: 'public-read',
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      UPLOADED_FILE_NAME = Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname;
      cb(null, UPLOADED_FILE_NAME);
      }
     })
    }).array('file');

    app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function (err) {

        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          return res.status(500).json(err)
          // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
         } else if (err) {
           return res.status(500).json(err)
          // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
       }
      console.log('REQUEST FILE IS', UPLOADED_FILE_NAME)
      return res.status(200).send(UPLOADED_FILE_NAME)

      // Everything went fine.
      })
});
```